# mySQL subquery. select from inferred data

Tags: mysql, subquery

So I have a mySQL db with some tables and data.

tables:

```
group_list
-groupID

location_list
-locationID
-groupID


staff
-locationID
-name
```

A group can have 1 or many locations.
A location can have 1 or many staff.
staff can only have 1 location.
location can only have 1 group.

How do I go about writing a query to get the names of all staff members in a group?

Comment: Please at least show some of effort on your side first to solving the problem. What have you reasoned about the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT s.name
FROM staff s INNER JOIN location_list l
ON s.locationID = l.locationID
INNER JOIN group_list g
ON l.groupID = g.groupID
WHERE g.groupID = 'some_group'
```

Comment: thats it! I didn't know about the inner join keyword. 
Thanks for your help